# Error initializing Cordova:missing command error in windows phone 8.1

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am working on windows universal apps using cordova. I have updated cordova.js from 3.2.0 to 3.6.3 and when I run the app in windows phone emulator, I am getting this error:

```
Error initializing cordova:missing command error
```

Can you please guide me how to solve this error?

Thanks In Advance,

Ajay

Comment: Have you solved that issue @ajay Kumar

Comment: @aorfevre I had the same issue and solved it. I posted my solution.

Comment: I had to restart my mac, now its all working fine...

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that some cordova related files are missing, particularly plugin files. Removing and adding the plugins again and/or removing and adding the platform should fix this error.

```
// do this for all plugins, or one at a time, testing in between
cordova plugins remove [plugin-name]
cordova plugins add    [plugin-repo]

// and if that doesn't help, do this
cordova platforms remove [platform]
cordova platforms add    [platform]
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by going into the Android SDK and just installing older versions of Android, plus all the associated tools. I'm not sure which one did it but once they were installed it worked properly.

I'm using Windows 7 plus the latest version of PhoneGap.